# Angular Error NG8001 - 'ngx-contentful-rich-text' is not a known element

Tags: angular, contentful

I'm trying to use the following library to convert Contentful Rich Text Field to HTML with some custom renderers.

https://github.com/kgajera/ngx-contentful-rich-text

For some reason, I am getting the following error which I surmise is somehow related to how I import the module above.  I believe I am importing the NgxContentfulRichTextModule properly so I am not sure why the CustomParagraphComponent template cannot find it?

#### Error

ERROR in src/app/post/post.component.ts (CustomParagraphComponent template):2:28 - error NG8001: 'ngx-contentful-rich-text' is not a known element:

1. If 'ngx-contentful-rich-text' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-contentful-rich-text' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

#### App.Module.Ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { HeaderComponent } from './navigation/header/header.component';
import { SidenavListComponent } from './navigation/sidenav-list/sidenav-list.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './navigation/footer/footer.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';
import { PostCardComponent } from './post-card/post-card.component';
import { FeatureInfoComponent } from './feature-info/feature-info.component';
import { FeatureCardComponent } from './feature-card/feature-card.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from './privacy/privacy.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContributeComponent } from './contribute/contribute.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

import { NgxContentfulRichTextModule } from 'ngx-contentful-rich-text';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidenavListComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    PostComponent,
    PostCardComponent,
    FeatureInfoComponent,
    FeatureCardComponent,
    PrivacyComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContributeComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    NgxContentfulRichTextModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### Post.Component.Ts

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
import { ContentfulService } from '../contentful.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BLOCKS, MARKS, Document } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';
import {
  CHILDREN,
  NodeRenderer
} from 'ngx-contentful-rich-text';


@Component({
  template: `
    <p class="text-center">${CHILDREN}</p>
  `,
})
export class CustomParagraphComponent extends NodeRenderer {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  public postSlug;
  post: Entry<any>;
  document: Document;

  // nodeRenderers: Record<string, Type<NodeRenderer>> = {
  //   [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: CustomParagraphComponent,
  // };

 nodeRenderers: Record<string, Type<NodeRenderer>> = {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: CustomParagraphComponent,
  };

  constructor(
    public contentfulService: ContentfulService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postSlug = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.contentfulService.getPost(this.postSlug).then(post => 
      { 
        this.post = post;
        this.document = this.post.fields.body;
        console.log(this.document);
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewChecked');
    if(this.post != null ) {
      console.log('NOT NULL');
      this.contentfulService.returnHTMLfromRichText(this.post.fields.body);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomParagraphComponent` is not included in the library. It is only shown in the readme as an example of how to use a custom component.

However, you can fix that by adding the `CustomParagraphComponent` to the `declarations` array in `AppModule`.